# Python - Class function wont run __init__

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python 3.5 and wonder if someone can point me in the right direction. I have a simple GUI and wish to load some data into the program but cant seem to get the class to work so I am obviously forgetting something. Can you guys help. Below is my code for the GUI.

```
from tkinter import *

def load_dat():
    import load_data
def doNothing(info=""):
    if info != "":
    print(info)
    status.config(text=info)
else:
    print("Ok I wont...")
    status.config(text="Ok I wont...")

root = Tk(className="Test GUI")

# ***** Main Menu *****

menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

subMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Load/Save", menu=subMenu)

loadSubmenu = Menu(menu)
loadSubmenu.add_command(label="Load Data")
subMenu.add_cascade(label='Load', command=load_dat)
subMenu.add_command(label="Save", command=doNothing)

# ***** Main Area *****

main_window = Frame(root, width=200, height=100)
main_window.pack()

# ***** Status Bar *****

status = Label(root, text="Preparing to do nothing", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

root.mainloop()
```

The code for my class (Called load_data) is:

```
class load_data:
print("0")
def __init__(self):
    print("1")
```

When I click on the "Load Data" button I can get the program to output the print"0" message but it wont output the print("1") message. What am I forgetting? Thanks for any help you can provide me.

Comment: You never create an instance of `load_data`, so of course the function that initializes instances of `load_data` won't run.

Comment: The code for the class definition should be indented.

Comment: Thanks user2357112 , can you give me a bit more detail. I dont understand what I need to do.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Like user2357112 already said, you never create an instance of your load_data class. The `__init__()` function of a class is called when it is instantiated. You should change your code like this:

```
# fixed indentation
class load_data:
    print("0")
    def __init__(self):
        print("1")
```

and:

```
from tkinter import *
import load_data  # import always at the start of a script

def load_dat():
    data = load_data()  # create an instance "data" of class "load_data"
def doNothing(info=""):
    if info != "":
    print(info)
    status.config(text=info)
else:
    print("Ok I wont...")
    status.config(text="Ok I wont...")
```